# Ajax: "no element found" when trying to call a PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to get JavaScript and PHP working together on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system. To that end, I have created the following three files:

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="testJS.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onClick="testFunction();">Click Me</button>
        <div id="testDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**testJS.js**

```
function testFunction() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "testPHP.php",
        success: function(result) {
            $("#testDiv").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

**testPHP.php**

```
<?php
echo("<h1>This is coming from PHP.</h1>");
?>
```

All of the above files are stored together within a single file on my desktop. Upon opening index.html in Firefox, and upon clicking the button, nothing happens to the web page and the Firefox console simply shows the following JavaScript errors:

```
no element found          testPHP.php:4:1
no element found          index.html:4:1
```

I have read other threads on this site regarding this issue. Adding `header('Content-Type: text/plain'); exit();` to my PHP file does not have any effect.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Update:** I have installed Apache2, confirmed it is working by viewing the Apache default page, and moved all three files to /var/www/html. I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: You are not running a local server??

Comment: first of that you should include `testJS.js` below `jquery.min.js` and you should use `baseURL + "testPHP.php"` as `ajax` url

Comment: I have tried your code and it's work fine for me. Tested in Chrome. Have you tested only in Firefox? Are you running on local or remote server? All the files are in the same directory?

Comment: epascarello, I don't see why it should make a difference. The php by itself works fine. The HTML and JS together work fine. JS and php just won't work together for some reason. fusion3k, I've only tested in Firefox. I'm not running on any server at all. Trying to run it on my laptop. All files in same directory.

Comment: so, going to testPHP.php in your browser shows large `This is coming from PHP.` - no <?php or anything

Comment: the code should work as long as it is hosted on a http server ... the error is repeatable if you are simply opening a file on your hard drive in the browser ... as @epascarello tried to tell you 36 minutes ago

Comment: It works fine for me also. Most likely your web server is not executing testPHP.php properly. Just run testPHP.php in browser, make sure it echo correctly, and rerun .html again.

Comment: @Yerke it sounds like the OP is not running a server at all....

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: I have now installed Apache2 on my machine and moved all files to the appropriate directory. I updated my original post. I am still experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Go directly to http://yourdomain/testPHP.php
What do you see? I think PHP was not installed in your server.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. Although PHP was installed on my machine, I had to do a separate installation of PHP specifically for Apache2. It's working now.

Comment: You should have that first :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```js
function testFunction() {
 
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>testPHP.php",
    type:"post",
    success: function(result) {
      $("#testDiv").html(result);
      alert(1)
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onClick="testFunction();">Click Me</button>
  <div id="testDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any explanations?